# scrape data VBA into excel

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

hi I want to scrape a single value from a fixed position on a website. my code is:

```
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
With appIE
.navigate "http://www.conferenceboard.ca/"
.Visible = True
End With
Do While appIE.Busy
DoEvents
 Loop

Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementById("product_cols_2")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(1).innerHTML

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing
Range("A1").Value = myValue
End Sub
```

I want to extract the "1.1" from the following code, but get a runtime error 438. I know my error is in the code "myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(1).innerHTML
" but being new to scraping via VBA I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have googled the issue relentlessly without luck. Appreciate any guidance, thanks

```
    <div class="triple" id="product_cols_2">
    <div>…</div>…
    <div>…</div>
    <h2>Data</h2>
    <div>
    <table class="ecoData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody> 
    <tr>    
     <td>
     Consumer Confidence
     <br> 
     <span class="metatext">Dec 2016, CBoC</span>
     </td>
     <td align="center" class="pGreen" style="padding-right: 6px;">1.1</td> 
     <td align="center">…</td>
```

Comment: I got the answer,

Comment: use Classnmae, not ID:    Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("pGreen")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData(0).innerText